# How to evaluate the following sum? $\sum_{i = 1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{3n-i}{2}\right\rfloor.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is the value of the following sum?  $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \left\lfloor \dfrac{3n-i}{2}\right\rfloor.$$
Especially how to handle the sums with floors?
This sum appeared while solving [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/APPROB/).

**My work:**
I tried ignoring floor and assuming that it will count an extra $\frac12$ for exactly $\left\lfloor \tfrac n2 \right\rfloor$ times, but the values do not match for the small test cases that I solve with hand.

Comment: Your correction is almost right;  however sometimes it should be $\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil$.  Try different $n$ and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is only for $n$ even. For $n$ odd, it can be done similarly.

Write $n=2k$ for some integer $k$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n \left\lfloor \dfrac{3n-i}{2}\right\rfloor&=\sum_{i = 1}^{2k} \left\lfloor \dfrac{6k-i}{2}\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{i \textrm{ even}}^{2k} \left\lfloor \dfrac{6k-i}{2}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i \textrm{ odd}}^{2k} \left\lfloor \dfrac{6k-i}{2}\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lfloor \dfrac{6k-2i}{2}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lfloor \dfrac{6k-(2i-1)}{2}\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lfloor 3k-i\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\lfloor 3k-i+\frac12\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} ( 3k-i)+\sum_{i=1}^{k} (3k-i)\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^{k} ( 3k-i).
\end{align}

I am sure from this point you can continue by yourself, can't you?

Comment: Thanks!
Just to verify my work, is the answer for the odd case $2\sum\limits_{i= 1}^k (3k - i + 1)$, where $n = 2k + 1$?

Answer (score 1):

We start with a special case of the [Hermite Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity), which states that $\forall x \in \Bbb R, \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor x+ \frac {1}{2}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor2x\right\rfloor.$ Substituting $x=\frac{3n-(i+1)}{2}$, we obtain $$\left\lfloor \frac{3n-i}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{3n-(i+1)}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor3n-(i+1)\right\rfloor=3n-(i+1).$$

Now check the cases when $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: I get for the even case from the other answer.
Can you verify whether the answer for the odd case is $2\sum\limits_{i= 1}^k (3k - i + 1)$ such that $2k+1 = k$?

Comment: Nope, I am finding the sum to be $5k^{2} + 4k +1$ where $2k+1=n$, but your's is coming out to be $5k^{2}+k.$

Comment: I see, I'll check my working. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\dfrac{3n-k}{2}\right\rfloor&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(n+\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-k}{2}\right\rfloor\right)\\
&=n^2+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\dfrac{k}{2}\right\rfloor\\
&=n^2+\left\lfloor\dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4}\right\rfloor
\end{align*}